# Excell Print VBA code combine with VBA Custom Footer

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a macro to print two sheets and include a custom footer that references several of the cells.

I have tried so many combinations, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I get the error `Object does not support this property or method`.

```
Sub PrintSummarySheet()

' PrintSummarySheet Macro

    Sheets("Project Data Input").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterFooter = .Range("C6").Text And .Range("F2").Text _
        And .Range("F4").Text And .Range("F5").Text

    End With
    Sheets(Array("Project Data Input", "Project Estimate Summary")).Select
    Sheets("Project Data Input").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("INSTRUCTIONS").Select
       Sheets("Project Data Input").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `With ActiveSheet.PageSetup` but on the next line you are trying to refer to the `Worksheet` and not the `PageSetup` by doing `.Range(...)`.

You need to replace `.Range(...)` by `ActiveSheet.Range(...)`.

The `Run-time error 13 Type mismatch` occurs because you are using `And` to concatenate text instead of the concatenation operator `&`

```
.Range("C6").Text And .Range("F2").Text _
    And .Range("F4").Text And .Range("F5").Text
```

Should be:

```
.Range("C6").Text & .Range("F2").Text & _
    .Range("F4").Text & .Range("F5").Text
```

Comment: Thank you!.  I tried but now I get an error " Run-time error 13 Type mismatch